# Android - Create a Slide in Slide Out Animation for webViews in a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-webview, android-animation, android-viewpager

I've implemented webViews within a ViewPager, but instead of the default animation (as seen with Launcher), I want to have a sliding animation.

Let's say I have 2 webviews. If I flick to the right, the left webview moves out of view and to the left and eventually becomes non visible, then the right webview moves left and becomes fully visible. I need there to be an instant where nothing appears on the viewPager during the transition.

Is this easily done with viewPager or do I have to scrap it and work with Animations completely?

I have found a good source to do it with pure animation but it may be hard to implement for webviews: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/137

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewpager doesn't match to your needs I think. use ViewFlipper instead and you can custom in/out animations.

Comment: Hmm, okay I guess I will try out ViewFlipper. With ViewFlippers, it seems that the views need to be added within the XML. I have the webviews in separate XML files, is ViewFlipper easier to implement if they views are all in 1 XML?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. Is there a way to disable infinite flipping though? ie. having 5 views. The views should be able to flip next and previous for each page except page 1 (only next) and page 5 (only previous).

Comment: that's easy. as I know infinite flipping is not default.

Comment: Well I have not set anything in my code to change the default. We have decided that we want the behavior of a viewpager instead anyway, though. But thanks!